# pseudo interactive ssh script

Tags: shell-script, ssh

I need to run a script that `ssh`s to another machine on my local network,(I've RSA key paired them), after `ssh`ing in, I need to run a command and get the results of the command in the local script (to parse), and then run another command built from some of the info from the first command.

Here is a step by step account of what I want to do:

- `ssh` into a machine running FileMaker Server 11
- get a list of the clients
- search for a certain client
- if that client is logged on, get its ID from the list
- send a Disconnect ID command to the FileMaker server
- exit out.

Hope this isn't too garbled.

Answer (score 1):

something like:

```
#!/bin/sh
clients=$(ssh server "get-list-of-clients")
myclient=$(echo $clients | grep my-client-name)
myclientid=$(echo $myclient | sed -e 's/^.*id=\([0-9]*\).*$//')
ssh server "kill-client-with-id $myclientid"
```

- first line connects to the server and requests list of clients (of course you'll replace server name and command to get list of clients with correct ones)
- second line extracts just client you want
- third line extracts just client id you want using `sed(1)`, preserving only number from  `id=1234` part of the line (you'll need to edit this probably, unless format happens to be just that)
- fourth line connects to remote server to kill specified client

Comment: Jeff;  1st: I, MEANT, to check back in the next day for responses, but Life and Work got in the way. 2nd: THANK you!  That looks pretty close to what I want to do, and gives me some examples of usage that I didn't realize I could do.

Comment: @RusselMcGaha welcome to the site, and I'm grad it was of help! You should click triangle up to upvote useful answers, and click checkbox an answer that solved your problem, to help other users of the site. Thanks!